# Navicat Premium Essentials - Mac OS Maverick

Tags: osx-mavericks

Do anyone know why since Maverick update, Navicat can't connect anymore to any database which is saved into "/Users/Username" folder?

It keeps saying: "Database file path is not correct". If I copy/paste the same DB in any other folder it connects perfectly. I need to open DBs in that folder because that's the folder where Xcode put the Apps ones and I can't everytime I need to modify them, copy/paste them on my desktop and then put them back again.

Comment: I've submitted a ticket to navicat about this problem. Hope they answer soon, and will update my post if I hear back from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using the app store version of navicat. It worked fine in snow leopard, but in mavericks it can't read or write files in my home directory. I assume that this is due to changes in the app sandboxing in mavericks, and that once navicat update their capability requirements in the app store it will be fixed.

In the meantime there are a couple of workarounds:

- Download navicat from their site. It is not limited by sandboxing and works normally. The trial lasts for 30 days, hopefully navicat will release an update before then.
- Put your data somewhere else with less restrictive permissions. I have moved mine to a root directory.

I have used both methods, but prefer the second as I can continue to use my installed and configured copy of navicat.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to submit a ticket to [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/support/submit-ticket) as I don't think someone can help you here.

Comment: Already did. I was searching for a shortcut.

Comment: did you thought about symbolic links?

Answer (score 0):

Have exactly the same problem. I think it is a language localization problem, where Navicat is unable to resolve the file path for non english versions of OSX Maverix.  I copied my DB-file to an external USB drive, doubled clicked the DB-file, and it opened normally.